# Firebase background function triggered late

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Some Firestore background functions seem to have been triggered some minutes after actual Firestore documents were updated:

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/followings/{followingUserId}')
      .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const now = moment();
        if(moment.duration(now.diff(moment(context.timestamp))).as("seconds") >= 150) {
          console.info("now: ", JSON.stringify(now));
          console.info("context.timestamp: ", 
           JSON.stringify(context.timestamp));
          ...
        }
        ...
```

This is what was in the logs:

```
 <function_name> 428884432521740 context.timestamp:  "2019-03-10T23:28:52.458755Z" I  <function_name> 428884432521740
 <function_name> 428884432521740 now:  "2019-03-10T23:33:25.297Z" I  <function_name> 428884432521740
```

Firestore's [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees) states:

```
It may take up to 10 seconds for a function to be triggered after a change to Cloud Firestore data
```

Why was it taking a lot longer than expected for the background function to be triggered?

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly for issues related to your perceived quality of service of Firebase products.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thanks, Doug. We only have community support at the moment.